# EXM newsletter content not displaying in gmail ([Message clipped])

Tags: exm

In our project we are using EXM 3.4 and SItecore 8.2 update 2. When we are sending emails form EXM, mail body content is not displaying correctly. It always generating one hyper link like below.

[Message clipped]  View entire message

In here clicking on "View entire message" hyperlink is displaying in browser window. But as per our requirement we have to display content directly in Email body.

Note: in Outlook content is displaying correctly.

If anyone come accross the same issue please let me know the solution.

Thanks for your help in advance:)

Answer (score 8):

When you send a message and the body section of the message exceeds 102KB, your Gmail subscribers will see the first 102KB of content and then see the following:

Gmail message clipped notification.

Please have a look on these links:

https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/205678278-Why-is-my-message-clipped-in-Gmail- 
 https://fulcrumtech.net/resources/preventing-gmail-from-clipping-your-emails/

What can you do to avoid your email being clipped by gmail?

**Include only relevant information in your emails**. To provide additional information, add hyperlinks that take users to your website.

**Avoid copying and pasting content from a word-processing program or a website**. This practice may add extra formatting code to your email’s underlying code without you realizing it.

**Use fluid hybrid design to create responsive email**s. This technique is a hybrid of fluid design and traditional responsive design, which reduces the need for long media queries. Fluid hybrid design employs content blocks based on percentages that adapt to the screen size being used. Check out this article for more information about fluid hybrid design

**Minimize your code**. This would include, for example, removing comments from your code, as well as white spaces, double spaces, line breaks, and tabs. There are also online tools that can minimize email messages automatically, such as HTML Minifier and HTML compressor. It’s not a good idea to use such sites as Tiny.url or Bitly to shorten your URLs, however, because this practice may get your emails caught in spam filters. Keep in mind that once the code is minimized, it’s hard to read and work with, so make this your last step.

**Always preview your emails before sending them**. In addition to using online email testing tools such as Litmus and Email on Acid, you should also send the email to your own Gmail account, just to be sure it’s rendering correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the help as you mentioned i have removed the unnecessary code from the Main layout page after that its started working.